# sqlite3/python UPDATE queries succeeding, but changes to DB not persisting after exiting python shell

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have a Python script where I am trying to merge data from a CSV file into a SQLite spatial database. When I run the `UPDATE` queries to insert the CSV data into the DB table, they succeed (and I can verify from the python shell that it actually updated the records), but then when I exit Python shell, the database doesn't actually commit the changes. When I `exit()` and reconnect to the database in a new Python shell, it is back how it was originally, before the `UPDATE`.

The script is below. The Spatialite DB has all of the land parcels in the county, and information about them (parcel number, address, property values, etc), as well as the vector/polygon data for the parcel's geometry. The CSV file contains three fields `PARCEL_NO`, `OWNER`, `TAXPAYER`. I am trying to, for each parcel number in the database, UPDATE the records for that parcel to include the `OWNER` and `TAXPAYER` info from the CSV file in the DB table's `OWNER` and `TAXPAYER` fields:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

dbfile = './ThurstonParcelOwners.sqlite'
ownersfile = './parcel-data/parcels-owners.csv'

parcels = []
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''SELECT parcel_no from thurstonparcelowners''')
parcels = [parcel[0] for parcel in c.fetchall()]

owners = []
po = open(ownersfile, 'r')
cw = csv.reader(po, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for o in cw:
    owners.append(o)

owners = {field[0]:field[1:] for field in owners}

skipped = []
for p in parcels:
    try:
        owner = owners[p][0]
        taxpayer = owners[p][1]
        c.execute("""UPDATE thurstonparcelowners SET owner = ? WHERE parcel_no IS ?""", (owner, p))
        c.execute("""UPDATE thurstonparcelowners SET taxpayer = ? WHERE parcel_no IS ?""", (taxpayer, p))

    except KeyError:
        skipped.append(p)
```

... Again, the `UPDATE`s are succeeding, and when I run the script with `python -i` I can verify that it worked afterwards by running `SELECT` statements on the DB. But when I `exit()` the Python shell afterwards, the database doesn't retain the data.

Is there something I have to do with sqlite to commit/save the changes before I exit?

Comment: check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit

Comment: oh that was simple :) thanks! ... for other folks who might be reading this in the future, and don't want to open the link: I just need to run `c.commit()` to commit the changes after I'm done with the update.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you would have to use `conn.commit()` to commit the changes to the database.